# How might I diagram this sentence? What kind of phrase is this?

Tags: grammar, phrases, diagramming

I am trying to diagram this sentence

> Across the rolling sward,  toward the tree line where the moonlight could not penetrate, a gaggle of ghouls slinked slowly, a singular purpose driving them on their lumbering, protracted route.

and I do not how to diagram the last bit because I do not know what kind of phrase it is or what function that it specifically serves in the sentence.

Here is what I have so far:

[image]

There is nothing connecting this clause to the rest of the sentence. What could it possibly be?

Someone said that the last clause is ungrammatical, and that something like

> She ran to the forest, her heart broken.

is not correct, although I have seen this kind of sentence structure many times in literature and do not think it is wrong.

What is this kind of thing and how do I diagram it?

Comment: Whose sentence is that? What is its source?

Comment: To those too young to be aware of what "diagramming a sentence" means (like me), please refer to [this article](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/diagrams2/one_pager1.htm), which covers the act of forming a sentence diagram in great detail.

Comment: @WeatherVane It is a sentence made up by a friend that does not have any source. I asked him for a sentence and this was the result.

Comment: That sentence is perfectly grammatical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a **parenthetical** phrase (a parenthesis).  Both of your examples are of the type called an absolute phrase (because they don't reuse a mentioned item).

Comment: +1 for "absolute": it is indeed an absolute construction. It could be argued that absolute constructions are parenthetical, but I don't think we normally call them that. So I would instead make *absolute construction* bold if I were you. You might also want to add that the same applies to the second example sentence.

Comment: I did mention both examples, and Wikipedia lists *absolute phrase* under the *parenthesis (rhetoric)* heading, so I'll need more evidence before changing my answer.

Comment: @Cerberus: God, how did I miss that? You did indeed mention both examples. // I didn't mean to say that *parenthesis* was wrong—just that it is less specific. We normally primarily use the more specific term absolute rather than the more general one. That's why it sounds a bit odd to me to make the term bold that we don't often use when naming the phaenomenon. Readers might think that this is a typical/common example of parenthesis, which it's obviously not. But it's ultimately not super important.

Comment: I see your point.  I find 'absolute' by itself to have too many applications, unless I can call it an *absolute parenthetical*.  If *absolute construction* is the accepted term, then I'll allow anyone to edit.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. I was able to diagram the sentence successfully and am very pleased. It turns out you just put absolute phrases above the main sentence.

Comment: Sorry -- I hadn't considered how to draw it.  I'd be tempted to link it like an adverbial phrase, but with a dotted line (meaning there may be some hidden preposition ['with'] that makes the construction more than coincidental).

Comment: Reed-Kellogg diagrams are designed for simple sentences. The do lay bare the relations of simple transitive and intransitive sentences quite nicely, and that's why their use is limited to grammar school, if it is taught at all. When one analyzes a complex sentence that has many subordinate clauses, like most of ordinary English, R-K diagrams are not useful -- they take up way too much space, for one thing, and one is never sure how various types of subordination are to be handled, because R-K rules predate modern structural analyses. It's like calculating a spreadsheet with a slide rule.

Comment: Like X-bar is better? ;)